# Pass Array to the XLPagerTabBar delegate function to open VC

Tags: ios, swift, xlpagertabstrip

i'm working with the third party lib `XLPagerTabBarStrip`. it has delegate

```
override func viewControllers(for pagerTabStripController: PagerTabStripViewController) -> [UIViewController]
```

Now i'm trying to pass my array that contains the storyboard identifiers names. I'm running for loop to get the name and than pass that to my return statement. When i run the app it shows only last item of array. How can i pass all items of array to the return statement? My code is this,

```
var child1 = UIViewController()

 override func viewControllers(for pagerTabStripController: PagerTabStripViewController) -> [UIViewController] {

    let viewController = ["LoggedInVC","RegisterationVC"]

    for items in viewController{
        child1 = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: items)

    }
    return [child1]
}
```

When i run the app it only shows vc with identifier `RegisterationVC`. How can i show both at once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `var child1` is of type `UIViewController` and you override this variable every time your loop is executed.

What you need is an Array of `UIViewController`

Try this:

```
 override func viewControllers(for pagerTabStripController: PagerTabStripViewController) -> [UIViewController] {

    var childs = Array<UIViewController>()

    let viewControllers = ["LoggedInVC","RegisterationVC"]

    for item in viewControllers {
        childs.append(UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: item))
    }

    return childs
}
```

Comment: if i have dynamic array , can this be done by this method? @Teetz

Comment: @raheem What do you concretely mean with dynamic array? (You can edit your question if you want to provide more information)

Comment: no i'm just asking that if i had dynamic array than this method could be written? @Teetz

Comment: just fill the array of identifiers which you need depending on what you want to achieve.